# PHP Mailer (Reusable form) - with WordPress : Works great, except for file attachment

Tags: wordpress, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I'm using a reusable form, a great tool which can be found here : http://reusableforms.com
It works with Phpmailer. I configured it to work on my WordPress page, which is a custom theme. For this, I had to change the src and URL of some file inside the code to make it works with WordPress. For example, in my form-section.php :

```
url: 'handler.php'
```

Had to be edit like that to work with WordPress:

```
url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/form-section/handler.php'
```

So the forms works really great : I can receive mails from that form.
The only problem is the Files attachment function wont work in the WordPress environment. It works well outside it, i tested it with those instructions : http://reusableforms.com/d/a/html-email-form-with-attachment.

But I need it in my WordPress environment. Maybe it's a src / URL problem that comes from here?

```
    private function attach_files()
{
    
    foreach($this->attachments as $file_field)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($file_field, $_FILES))
        {
            continue;
        }
        $filename = $_FILES[$file_field]['name'];

        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($filename));

        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], 
            $uploadfile))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $this->mailer->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
    }
}
```

Thank you, I would really appreciate any advice

Comment: If you are using ajax to send the mail it will not attached because the mail has sent before the attached completed. SO you have to change the condition like if ----attached---upload--it keep it on server temp then sent with the kept server file and remove the attached file. I have the same issue before and it solved.

Comment: Thanks Firefrog but im not a developper, I dont know how to do this :/